# Perl how to drop decimal points if 00

Tags: perl, cpan, template-toolkit

I have a string being generated passed to and outputed by template toolkit using:

https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Plugin::Number::Format

Its using `format_price` I want to drop the cents off the price if they are zero. So 100.00 becomes 100

Can't find any clear solution to this.

Update:

`format_price` is used in hundreds of places within this project and if possible i'd like to not change that and override the method with this functionality if possible.

Comment: Is there any requirement to do this only using the module? Otherwise use sprintf to format how you want.

Comment: No requirement on the module if I could get something to pipe it to in template toolkit that would work.

Comment: `format_price($precision) : Returns a string containing "$number" formatted similarly to "format_number()", except that the decimal portion may have trailing zeroes added ...` Is there any particular reason you can't use `format_number` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `Template::Plugin::Number::Format` to create your own plugin like so:

```
package Template::Plugin::My::Number::Format;
use base qw(Template::Plugin::Number::Format);
use Number::Format;

sub init {
    my ($self, $config) = @_;
    $self->SUPER::init($config);
    my $nfo = Number::Format->new(%$config);
    $self->{ _CONTEXT }->define_filter(format_price => sub {
        my ($context, @args) = @_;
        return sub {
            my $text = shift;
            my $result = $nfo->format_price($text, @args);
            $result =~ s/\.00$//;
            return $result;
        };
    }, 1);
    return $self;
}
```

Then inside your templates you would use your plugin like so:

```
[% USE My.Number.Format %]
...
[% some_number | format_price %]
```

Comment: This is of course the simplest way to override the default behaviour (much more so than my answer), but I got the distinct impression that the OP wanted to avoid modifying existing templates.

Answer (score 1):

It should be relatively straightforward to implement an override of this function to behave as you require.

The plugin code is almost trivial in what it does. Take a copy of it from wherever you have it installed and make it part of your code-base, so your version is the one that will be found during compilation, i.e.

`Myapp/lib/Template/Plugin/Number/Format.pm`

edit it thus:

```
-use Number::Format;
+use Number::Format::NoZeroCents;
```

Then add a new module to your code:

`Myapp/lib/Number/Format/NoZeroCents.pm;`

that looks like this:

```
package Number::Format::NoZeroCents;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Number::Format';

sub format_price {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($number, $precision, $symbol) = @_;
    if(defined $precision){ #default behaviour
        printf STDERR "%s: default behaviour for %s\n", __PACKAGE__, join(';',@_);
        return $self->SUPER::format_price(@_)
    }
    else {
        $precision = 0 if $number == int($number);
        printf STDERR "%s: override behaviour for %s\n", __PACKAGE__, $number;
        return $self->SUPER::format_price($number, $precision, $symbol)
    }
}

1;
```

And that should mean your NoZeroCents approach is used by default throughout your code, but you can override by calling `[% number | format_price(2) %]` when you want $100.00 to appear.

---

**UPDATE**

Number::Format definitely does the right thing when told to use precision => 0, as this quick test confirms:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Number::Format qw(format_price);

my $v = 100.00;

printf "Original value as string '%s'; as number '%f'; as fp '%s'; as fp0: '%s'\n",
       $v, $v, format_price($v), format_price($v,0);
```

which produces:

```
Original value as string '100'; as number '100.000000'; as fp 'AUD 100.00'; as fp0: 'AUD 100'
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution but I am getting an error with this implementation I am not sure about

`Warning caught during route execution: Useless use of a variable in void context at /opt/public-site/lib/Number/Format/NoZeroCents.pm line 8.
/opt/public-site/lib/Number/Format/NoZeroCents.pm around line 8
 5 use base 'Number::Format';
 6 
 7 sub format_price {
 8     my ($self, $number, $precision, $symbol) = shift, @_;
 9     if(defined $precision){ #default behaviour
10         $self->SUPER::format_price(@_)
11     }`

Comment: I've made some minor adjustments. Naughty me for leaving out strict/warnings in new module, and I made the parent's `format_price()` calls explicitly return, which I suspect was the cause of the 'useless use' warning.

Comment: this works better. Now I'm having an issue overriding the existing module. I"m using this in a Perl Dancer project and have copied both these files into my ./lib directory. However it dosen't seem to get called. What should I look for and How can I confirm it is loaded correctly?

Comment: Presumably you've included the full paths as described, and the 'lib' directory is where all your perl code lives? (My framework experience is Catalyst, but same general principles apply. What we've done here is classic perl sub-classing and overriding techniques, the framework isn't relevant really.) Add a line to each of your new modules just before the `1;` finish that reads `printf "**** %s ****\n", __PACKAGE__ ;`, and see if that gets output in your development server's log when you start it up. If it doesn't, you've got issues with your perl path.

Comment: The lines get output and look correct. `-- /opt/public-site/lib/Template/Plugin/Number/Format.pm updated.
Killing the existing server (pid:14257)
2013/02/06-10:11:36 Server closing!
**** Number::Format::NoZeroCents ****
**** Template::Plugin::Number::Format ****
Successfully killed! Restarting the new server process.
Setting gid to "33 33 33"
Starman: Accepting connections at http://*:5000/`
However I am skeptical of the top line that says Format.pm was updated. I also don't see the behavior in my views.

Comment: If you're seeing those messages, your modules are being loaded. I've added some debug lines as an example of how you might track down the problem. I took a quick look at the source code for `Number::Format`, and it looks like it should do the right thing when you want precision=0 in a `format_price()` call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the extra zeros are especially for currency mode.

> format_price($precision)
>   Returns a string containing "$number" formatted similarly to "format_number()", except that the decimal portion may have trailing zeroes added to make it be exactly "$precision" characters long, and the currency string will be prefixed.

If you still want to avoid it, I guess just not using this mode will suffice